# How to programmatically embed a canned service with Express generator app in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, npm

I am new to NodeJS and I am trying to implement canned library (http://sideshowcoder.github.io/canned/) with Express Generator. But I after reading the docs, I can't understand how to embed it with an app generated by express generator?

Following is a way described in the docs to embed it.

```
 var canned = require('canned')
 ,   http = require('http')
 ,   opts = { logger: process.stdout }

can = canned('/path/to/canned/response/folder', opts)

http.createServer(can).listen(3000)    //This line is confusing
```

Now when I created an app using express-generator, i found the following line in `bin\www` :

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Where app is the default app created by express-generator. Now I am confused because in canned library docs, we are supposed to send `can` app to the `createServer` function but in express generator it is already sending `app` to the same function.

I have a canned(mock) api `/profile/index.get.json` which I need to access.

Now, How can I embed it in this app?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The main problem here is that express and canned both do the same thing: they reply to browser requests. When the browser sends a request to `localhost:3000`, you cannot have both express and canned send back a reply. I'm not sure what your goal is here; are you trying to use express to send back static files (like HTML documents and stylesheets) and use canned to mock a database?

Comment: I am using express to send back canned responses

Comment: No, you're not listening. Normally, you would use express and a database to create an API. The browser requests data, express connects to the DB, compiles the result and sends it back as response to the request. However, if you just need a mock API, setting all that up is tedious, so this is why canned exists. It completely replaces express, using json files instead of express and a DB. So "I am using express to send back canned responses" is nonsense, since canned *does the exact same thing* as a simple express mock api does.

Comment: This is why you're confused by `http.createServer(can).listen(3000)`: because that line creates a fully-fledged HTTP server who already responds to API requests. No express needed.

Comment: Is it possible to send responses from canned folder on a specific route of express app (say  `/api/`) ? like `/api/profile` should return response from `canned-folder/profile/index.get.json` ? Maybe we can use app.use() to embedd the canned folder for that route?

Comment: No. This is explained as [the very first thing in the docs](http://sideshowcoder.github.io/canned/) you linked: if you want your routes to start with `/api/`, just create a folder called `api` and put your json files in there. *However*: if you want some of your routes to be served by express and others by canned, that's a different story. Not sure that's possible in the first place, it's probably simpler to implement a canned-like middleware in express in that case.